# JQuery : Inline JS to External JS

Tags: jquery

I have several inline jqueries, how can I move them into one single external .js file?

Below are the inline functions I created using JQuery

Inline Functions:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#showReport").click(function() {
                var val = $('input:radio[name=reportOption]:checked').val();

                if(val == 'frame'){
                    document.getElementById("form").target = '_self';
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("form").target = '_blank';
                }

                if(document.form.fromDate.value=='' || document.form.toDate.value==''){
                    alert("Please enter Date Range");
                }
                else{
                    document.form.submit();
                }
            })
    });
```

Comment: ...Copy > Paste into an external `.js` file

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I really need to move the inline functions into external file, because it is really long, I just post one function in my question but there are more than 10 functions, thus it makes the jsp look very "ugly". BTW, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just save that function to a js file called `javascript.js`, put that file in the same directory of your html file and write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

At the end of your html file (just before your closing `</body>` tag)